# Cannot resolve symbol 'Paint' android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was working fine on my project in android studio. I suddenly open it and it shows many `Cannot resolve symbol`

For example

```
private Paint p = new Paint();
```

gives `Cannot resolve symbol 'Paint'`

Although the package is imported

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
```

Another example this one too

```
txtBarCode.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(25)});

Cannot resolve symbol 'InputFilter'

import android.text.InputFilter;
```

Everything was working perfectly , I don't understand what changed.

I tried to build , clean , rebuild and also deleteing .idea folder

Comment: Despite the IDE errors, can you build the project? Also, try File>Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Yes I can build it and run it without issues. for invalidate caches is there any side effect of it?

Comment: As far as I know there won't be any sideeffects for invalidating caches

Comment: It's working! thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that, I will post my comment as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IDE errors like that (when you still can build/run project but IDE's flashing red errors all over the place) most of the time invalidating caches should help. You can do that by selecting File -> Invalidate caches and restart